# Apache Pig only load first nested tuple

Tags: apache-pig

I use the exact sample from [official document](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.17.0/basic.html#schemas):

I have data.txt:

```
(3,8,9) (mary,19)
(1,4,7) (john,18)
(2,5,8) (joe,18)
```

I run:

```
A = LOAD 'data.txt' AS (F:tuple(f1:int,f2:int,f3:int),T:tuple(t1:chararray,t2:int));
dump A
```

I always got:

```
((3,8,9),)
((1,4,7),)
((2,5,8),)
```

The second nested tuple never got loaded. I tried in both versions of 0.16.0 and 0.17.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The problem should be with the data file you created.* There should be ***tab*** in between both tuples as separator in the data file while creating it. If there was a ***space*** then we need to change the load query accordingly.

**a)With tab(\t) as delimiter or separator.**

```
grunt> A = LOAD '/home/ec2-user/data' AS (F:tuple(f1:int,f2:int,f3:int),T:tuple(t1:chararray,t2:int));
grunt> DESCRIBE A;
A: {F: (f1: int,f2: int,f3: int),T: (t1: chararray,t2: int)}
grunt> dump A;
((3,8,9),(mary,19))
((1,4,7),(john,18))
((2,5,8),(joe,18))
```

**b)With single space( ) as delimiter or seperator.**

```
grunt> A = LOAD '/home/ec2-user/data' AS (F:tuple(f1:int,f2:int,f3:int),T:tuple(t1:chararray,t2:int));
grunt> DESCRIBE A;
A: {F: (f1: int,f2: int,f3: int),T: (t1: chararray,t2: int)}
grunt> dump A;
((3,8,9),)
((1,4,7),)
((2,5,8),)
```

**#Use PigStorage(' ') in case if you still want to use space as delimiter for file.**

```
grunt> A = LOAD '/home/ec2-user/data' USING PigStorage(' ') AS (F:tuple(f1:int,f2:int,f3:int),T:tuple(t1:chararray,t2:int));
grunt> DESCRIBE A;
A: {F: (f1: int,f2: int,f3: int),T: (t1: chararray,t2: int)}
grunt> dump A;
((3,8,9),(mary,19))
((1,4,7),(john,18))
((2,5,8),(joe,18))
```